# Unit test Spring and PowerMock - Getting null pointer in request.getParameter value

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito, spring-test-mvc

Hi I have the following code to test:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displayPages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView errorPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = (request != null) ? request.getParameter("tok") : "";
        boolean requestP = ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("Request Param", tok, "HTTPParameterValue", 1, false);
        if (requestP || token.contains(msg.getMessage("techErr.tok", new Object[]{}, Constants.LOCAL))) {
            return new ModelAndView("dispError");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("login");
        }

    }
```

Part of my unit test class is shown below:

```
  @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({ESAPI.class})
    public class ApplicationConTest {

          @InjectMocks
        private ApplicationCont appController;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        ....

         @Before
        public void setup() {

            MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();


            MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
            request.setSession(session);
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(appController).build();

        }

 @Test
    public void errorPages_ExpectLogout() throws Exception {

        String returnVal = "test";

        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       


        when(request.getParameter("tok")).thenReturn("dummuy value");



        when(msg.getMessage("techErr.tok",new Object[]{},Constants.LOCAL)).thenReturn(returnVal);

        //msg.getMessage("techErr.tok", new Object[]{}, Constants.LOCAL)


           mockMvc.perform(get("/errorPages"))
                .andExpect(view().name("logout")
                );
    }
```

When I execute the code the String tok is null and i get a null pointer exception. However as showed above I am returning a dummy value,
any advice why tok is null?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are using MockHttpServletRequest which basically mocks the request object then why do you want to mock the request object separately. You can set your attribute in the setup method or you can set it in test as well.

Comment: Hi when i comment out HttpServletRequest  and leave the MockHttpServletRequest  in the @Before method it is still null.

Comment: You can use MockHttpServletRequest and set the attribute.

Comment: I tried this request.setAttribute("tok", "tok"); in the @Before method  but it is still null

Comment: I think you should call like this mockMvc.perform(get("/errorPages").param("tok", "tok"))
                .andExpect(view().name("logout")
                );

Comment: Thanks works fine with the param("tok", "tok")